# What's the most concise way to set a variable to a getElementById's value or a default value if the element is not found?

Tags: javascript

I tried

```
var test = document.getElementById("some_element").value || "defaultvalue";
```

But since it returns `null`, that doesn't seem to work.

The shortest I could come up with so far is

```
var test = "defaultvalue";
if(document.getElementById("some_element") !== null) test = document.getElementById("some_element").value;
```

or

```
var test = (document.getElementById("some_element") !== null)?document.getElementById("some_element").value:"defaultvalue";
```

However, is there an even more concise way to write this fallback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new optional chaining operator in combination with `||`:

```js
var test = document.getElementById("some_element")?.value || "defaultvalue";
console.log(test);
```

This is pretty new syntax - like always, when writing scripts, to support older browsers, use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile for production.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) here:

```
var test = document.getElementById("some_element")?.value ?? "defaultvalue";
```

Answer (score 1):

The new operators are nice, but if you need full browser compatibility and don't [want to] use a transpiler, this may be the alternative:

```js
console.log( 
  (document.getElementById("nothing") || {value: null})
    .value ||"default" 
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter version without checking if it is null and using optional chaining

```js
var valueexists = document.getElementById("some_element")?.innerText ?? "defaultvalue";
var valuenotthere = document.getElementById("some_")?.innerText ?? "defaultvalue";
console.log(valueexists);
console.log(valuenotthere);
```

```html
<div id="some_element">value present</div>
```